# C# WPF Ellipse Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I just want to know if there is a way on how to make an ellipse slider with thumb like this one example I made in paint:

[image]

Right now I am using a `style` but only works on horizontal silders. Here is the sample code:

```
        <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border Height="4" >
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/FoodWare;component/Resources/draggerLine.png"></ImageBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                    <Border Height="4">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/FoodWare;component/Resources/draggerFull.png"></ImageBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="0" StrokeDashArray="0" StrokeMiterLimit="0" StrokeLineJoin="Round">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/FoodWare;component/Resources/draggerBtn1.png" ></ImageBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track"   >
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"  />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

If I try to replace the image with circle images, the circle is cut to a semi-circle and the slider moves horizontally. I'll be glad to here your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Rotating thumb, this isn't working 100%, but you should be able to get it from here, basically this draws a rectangle and allows you to rotate it. You could rotate the image you showed in your question, this would appear to be a slider, but really your just rotating an image. The broken part is the rotatethumb class is rotating the rectangle around the lower left corner instead of the center which is what you would want

Xaml:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:RotateThumb}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="Control">
            <Grid>
                <local:RotateThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    Cursor="SizeAll"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ContentControl Name="DesignerItem"
               Width="100"
               Height="100"
               Canvas.Top="100"
               Canvas.Left="100"
               Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

Thumb subclass:

```
public class RotateThumb : Thumb
{
    private double initialAngle;
    private RotateTransform rotateTransform;
    private Vector startVector;
    private Point centerPoint;
    private ContentControl designerItem;
    private Canvas canvas;
    public RotateThumb()
    {
        DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(this.RotateThumb_DragDelta);
        DragStarted += new DragStartedEventHandler(this.RotateThumb_DragStarted);
    }
    private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.designerItem = DataContext as ContentControl;
        if (this.designerItem != null)
        {
            this.canvas = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this.designerItem) as Canvas;
            if (this.canvas != null)
            {
                this.centerPoint = this.designerItem.TranslatePoint(
                new Point(this.designerItem.Width * this.designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin.X,
                this.designerItem.Height * this.designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin.Y),
                this.canvas);
                Point startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this.canvas);
                this.startVector = Point.Subtract(startPoint, this.centerPoint);
                this.rotateTransform = this.designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
                if (this.rotateTransform == null)
                {
                    this.designerItem.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
                    this.initialAngle = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.initialAngle = this.rotateTransform.Angle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void RotateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.designerItem != null && this.canvas != null)
        {
            Point currentPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this.canvas);
            Vector deltaVector = Point.Subtract(currentPoint, this.centerPoint);
            double angle = Vector.AngleBetween(this.startVector, deltaVector);
            RotateTransform rotateTransform = this.designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            rotateTransform.Angle = this.initialAngle + Math.Round(angle, 0);
            this.designerItem.InvalidateMeasure();
        }
    }
}
```

This was adapted from sukram's WPF Diagram Designer article on code project